# Remove 7 numbers (of any variant) before each instance of "|"

Tags: regex

I have huge file (17 million lines) that contains content in this format:

```
"AB101XG","57.144165160000000|","-2.114847768000000|";
"AB106RN","57.137879760000000|","-2.121486688000000|";
"AB107JB","57.124273770000000|","-2.127189644000000|";
"AB115QN","57.142701090000000|","-2.093014619000000|";
"AB116UL","57.137546630000000|","-2.112695886000000|";
"AB118RQ","57.135977620000000|","-2.072114784000000|";
"AB123FJ","57.098002900000000|","-2.077668775000000|";
....
```

to reduce the size, and as its not needed I want to remove the last 7 numbers before each | no other numbers etc should be removed.

Any ideas please, I'm using Textpad if that makes a difference

Thanks, Neil

Comment: Do you have any text processing tool installed, like either a proper Cygwin installation or at the very least, Perl itself?  It is unthinkable to do hacking on text without at least Perl, with which you can emulate/implement any of the others easily enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search for `[0-9]{7}\|` and replace it with just `|`.

Have a look at the [TextPad Quick Reference Card](http://johnbokma.com/textpad/textpad-reference.pdf) for a reference on the regular expression syntax in Textpad.

Comment: `[0-9]{7}\|` and replace it with `|`

Answer (score 1):

[0-9]{7}\|... you have to specify withink suqare brackets the symbol yo are looking for and after within curly brackets the number of instance consecutive you are looking for...

After you sustitute all with |

Comment: if you want to test a bit the regular expression befor using it i sudgest you to paste you data and the expression ou want to test on this website: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript example to illustrate the pattern needed.

```
var line = '"AB101XG","57.144165160000000|","-2.114847768000000|';

var result = line.replace(/\d{7}\|/, '|');

result ; //# =>  "AB101XG","57.14416516|","-2.114847768000000|
```

Will only match the first 7 digits followed by |